# Is it possible to have a form/questionnaire inside a marketing html email?

Tags: html, forms, html-email

I am wondering how I can place a small form/questionnaire inside a marketing email that I am sending out? With no php or javascript available I am wondering if there are ways this can be done.

Comment: Some email clients will permit a form in an email, but you'd still need something server-side to receive the data when they click submit. Given that, you're probably better off hosting the form off-email too and just having a "take the survey" button in the email.

Comment: thanks ceejayoz, I'm dealing with a client who has requested that it be inside the email itself. I was unsure of whether it was even possible so I'm trying to find a solution.

Comment: Our responsibility as professionals is often to say "no" to weird client demands (and explain why, and offer better alternatives).

Answer (score 0):

Having tried this myself, allow me to share my experience.

There is nothing stopping you from actually making an HTML Form inside an e-mail, but there are many e-mail clients out there. Some of them block "interactive" HTML, in particular, buttons. And you need a submit button to send your data.

In my job, we have implemented a new feature that allowed users to sign confidential documents by clicking a button on their e-mail. The email had a simple HTML form with a few  elements which identified the document to be signed. By pressing a submit button, the form did a POST submit to the server, opened the user's browser and directed him to the web site to sign. This worked for a while, until we had a customer using it via Outlook Web Mail. They claimed the system generated e-mails did not have a button they could push. After investigating, we discovered what I mentioned above. We ended up changing the button for a hyperlink. The information identifying the document now is attached to that link, and the link has been styled to look like a button. Links play well inside e-mails. Buttons don't. Hope this helps.

Comment: tutiplain thanks, I'll give it a try with a hyperlink

Comment: You should know that you probably won't be able to do a submit like you would with a button. In case, I included the info I needed to send from the email as part of the hyperlink's query string.